# How to have one script trigger another [j Query] Shrinking and expanding searchbox

Tags: jquery, html, menubar

Hey, I have a simple question, but I'll set up the scenario first.

I'm making a menu bar similar to that of apple.com (when the search bar is clicked it auto expands to show available user input)

Now I have a script that expands the search for when clicked an is as follows:

```
<script>
$("#searchbar").focus(function() {
$("#searchbar").animate(
        {width: 170},
        "medium");
});
$("#searchbar").blur(function() {
$("#searchbar").animate(
        {width: 92},
        "medium");
});
</script>
```

So I need to somehow shrink the rest of the menu bar, this is what I'm thinking: if I make the buttons in a separate div tag then just call upon the shrinking of the div when the search bar is clicked that should work fine.

The only problem is I do not know how to accomplish this task. That is why I have come to ask this question, I hope I am not asking a complete noobish question! :)

Thanks for all the help!
-John

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a `complete` callback to your `animate` functions.  See http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Callbacks happen after an event is done (animate in your case).

Comment: Okay, I was just reading that page. Thanks! Can you help me with specific code, would I add the code to resize the div buttons and call it when the search bar is clicked? Thanks again!